# How can I mimic Griffiths' electrodynamics textbook?

Tags: fonts, formatting

This is such a beautiful textbook; very dear to me. I think it has a great font - which I know is Times New Roman. But somehow, I can't even get close to it. One of the main obstacles is making the font thicker somehow. Anyways, here is a sample page. If anyone can translate it into TeX, I'd be impressed.

[image]

P.S. The main issue is to somehow make the Times New Roman font a little thicker. Here is my attempt - is there any way to make this look a little less corny?:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please also add the code you've written to create the excerpt you've posted. Useful answers to font-related questions will depend importantly on features such as the font family (or families) you're using.

Comment: 'Corny' is somewhat subjective and not something I normally use to describe the physically appearance of most things.  Can you be a little more specific?  If you use `fontspec`, you can tweak the 'weight' of your fonts pretty easily....

Comment: You can try by loading packages providing native support for times in math, i.e., `newtx` font (`newtxtext` anf newtxmath`).

Comment: I gotta go to bed now - this post will be revisited.

Comment: Wait - what do you mean, jon, by font spec?

Comment: I think font spec is for XeTeX only? I'm using Pdf LaTeX btw

Comment: The package `fontspec`, which requires the use of `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` (engines `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX` instead of `pdfTeX`) to do the typesetting.  That and OpenType or TrueType fonts (`.otf` or `.ttf`).  [Addendum: I figured you were, but you may want to consider the advantages of switching.]

Comment: Judging by the (to me at least!) pleasingly round and fairly thick large parentheses shown in the excerpt of Griffith's book, I would venture a guess that the publisher used a font package such as "MathTime Professional II". Other Times Roman math font packages -- such as `mathptmx`, `txfonts`, and even the more recent `newtxmath` -- all seem to produce rather anorexic-looking large parentheses. Which math font package do you use currently?

Comment: @Dave: Nice try there! Can you please the code that produced your output?

Comment: See above: that code is no more. It has ceased to be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### With `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

[image]

#### With `\usepackage{tgtermes}\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`

[image]

#### With `\usepackage{stix}`

[image]

#### With `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

[image]

#### Source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%% Uncomment one at a time
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{tgtermes}\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage{stix}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thesection{9.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\renewcommand\theequation{9.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{39}

\section{Electromagnetic Waves in Vacuum}

\subsection{The Wave Equation for $\vect{E}$ and $\vect{B}$}

In regions of space where there is no charge or current,
Maxwell's equations read
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{alignedat}{4}
&\text{(i)}\quad & \nabla\cdot\vect{E}&=0,\qquad
&&\text{(ii)}\quad & \nabla\times\vect{E}&=-\frac{\partial\vect{B}}{\partial t},
\quad\\
&\text{(iii)}\quad & \nabla\cdot\vect{B}&=0,\qquad
&&\text{(iv)}\quad & \nabla\times\vect{B}&=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\vect{E}}{\partial t}.
\quad
\end{alignedat}
\right\rbrace
\end{equation}
They constitute a set of coupled, first-order, partial differential equations
for $\vect{E}$ and $\vect{B}$. They can be \emph{de}coupled by applying the
curl to (iii)~and~(iv):
\begin{align*}
\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vect{E}) &=
  \nabla(\nabla\cdot\vect{E})-\nabla^2\cdot\vect{E}=
  \nabla\times\left(-\frac{\partial\vect{B}}{\partial t}\right)
\\[1ex]
&=
-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\times\vect{B})=
-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\vect{E}}{\partial t^2},
\\[2ex]
\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vect{B}) &=
  \nabla(\nabla\cdot\vect{B})-\nabla^2\cdot\vect{B}=
  \nabla\times\left(\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\vect{E}}{\partial t}\right)
\\[1ex]
&=
\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\times\vect{E})=
-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\vect{B}}{\partial t^2}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that the `mtpro2`, which is the exact answer, is wrong (I think it's the same as the `newtx`).

Comment: @Manuel You're right; I must have grabbed the wrong picture. The difference in the rendering of `\partial` is evident. Fixed.

Comment: @Marienplatz Indeed! `mtpro2` can be downloaded from http://pctex.com, while `stix` must be manually installed from CTAN.

Comment: As the nabla is a vector, should it be in bold?

Comment: @Marienplatz The boldness of nabla is a stylistic choice; for me it is *not* a vector: I'm a mathematician, you know. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: I see. You are apparently [an Algebra professor](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/a-new-milestone/). Anyway, do you shift the motorbike gear up without squeezing the clutch? :-)

Comment: @Marienplatz My motorbike has automatic transmission. ;-) Seriously, it's really a stylistic choice. That's not a vector, whatever physicists say: it's a covector field in a space of differential operators. The fact that scalar or vector product can be used is just formal and good so long as it produces correct formulas.

Comment: Touring with such an automatic transmission motorbike seems to be inconvenient (at least for me). :-) About the nabla, I will always use bold or arrow for it. Just to emphasize it is not a scalar. :-)

Comment: @Marienplatz As egreg says, it's stylistic choice. In my case, in LaTeX, I write it normal (not a vector). But handwritten, I usually add the vec arrow over the nabla in some cases to differentiate operators.

Comment: does mtpro2 work for mac? My computer doesn't have an application that can recognize the downloaded file.